# MPI: Change number of processors in CMakelists

Tags: c++, mpi, mpich, clion

I'm using CLion. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(MPI)

add_executable(MPI main.cpp)

# Require MPI for this project:
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPI_LINK_FLAGS})

include_directories(MPI_INCLUDE_PATH)
target_link_libraries(MPI ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

The MPI - Hello World runs well. **But how do I change the number of the processors in the cmakelists?**

I already tried to add -np 4 and -n 4 to the program arguments in CLion. But still I just get

> Hello World process 0 of 1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot specify number of processes to use in the CMakeLists.txt. Number of processes is an argument you specify when executing the program with mpirun.

To compile a mpi C project I use following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(hellompi)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(hellompi ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

In order to execute the program from Clion, I first changed the *(obscure)* location which Clion by default outputs compiled files to.
You can specify another location for the compiled files under the settings in "Build, Execution and Deployment" -> "CMake". I just changed it to the project folder.

Next I edited the run configurations. "Run" -> "Edit Configurations" -> set Executable to mpirun. (the location of mpirun on your machine)

Next I edited the "Program arguments" to be

```
-np 4 /home/mitzh/ClionProjects/hellompi/Debug/hellompi
```

To execute my program using 4 processes.

Comment: the nobel prize for this answer

Comment: Finally I found a CMakeLists that works! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I spent days trying to get this to work and this finally works. Even years later this is relevant

Answer (score 3):

The number of processors you use has nothing to do with the compilation process and thus has nothing to do with your CMakeLists.txt (besides when using CTest, but that is a different topic).

You just compile the executable, either using [`mpicxx`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www1/mpicxx.html) or the way you do now, and then run it with

```
mpirun -np 4 nameOfExe
```

Note that the `-np 4` is an argument to `mpirun`, not to your program.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know how to do it in CLion (IDE)? I mean I tried to add "-np 4" to the program arguments, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Joey I do not know CLion, though I think you need to run it through the mpi wrapper. Passing `-np 4` to the `nameOfExe` will not work.

Comment: @luk32 Thank you, but I do not know how to do it like you mentioned :( But I found this here: "set(MPIEXEC_MAX_NUMPROCS "2" CACHE STRING "Maximum number of processors available to run MPI applications.")" -> https://github.com/realstolz/powerlyra/blob/master/cmake/FindMPICH2.cmake 
So can you make it still in the CMakeList?

Comment: @Joey Again, this has nothing to do with compilation and CMake, but with how you execute the final binary. I don't know CLion and don't know if it can handle this special way of starting your binary. If not, just start it in a command line.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You're right. Thank you, in a terminal it's working of course. But it would be more pleasent if it would work with CLion :P

Comment: @joey Google "CLion mpirun" it yields some results how to define custom launcher or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

### OpenMP and MPI together

For those who would like to use both **OpenMP** and **MPI** within a single CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(parallel_task)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wall -pedantic -lm -O3 -funroll-loops")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

add_executable(parallel_task example.cpp example.h)

# OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP)
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(parallel_task PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
endif()

# MPI
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(parallel_task PUBLIC MPI::MPI_CXX)
```

or even **simpler**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(parallel_task)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# -fopenmp flag (enables OpenMP)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wall -pedantic -lm -O3 -funroll-loops -fopenmp")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")

add_executable(parallel_task example.cpp example.h)

# MPI
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(parallel_task PUBLIC MPI::MPI_CXX)
```

### Execute program from CLion

In order to run the program directly from CLion, click on `Edit Configurations...` and as *executable* set `mprirun` (location of the executable may be found by using the command `whereis` from a command line).

[image: How to edit configurations]

Inside *program arguments* set `-np <number of processes> <some other arguments>`. For example `-np 4 /home/desktop/parallel_task` will execute the program with 4 processes.

[image: Set executable and program arguments]