# Using CMake, Microsoft MPI and Visual Studio 2017 - cannot find mpi.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compiler-errors, mpi

I am trying to find/develop a very simple example of how to use CMake with Microsoft MPI with Visual Studio. I have CMake working well and generally understand it how to create CMake projects. I also have MS MPI working with Visual Studio and have confirmed I can create an MPI project following this example:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/

I just have not been able to get them working together. Specifically, I am looking for the CMake commands to put into my CMakeLists.txt file that enables MS MPI builds in Visual Studio 17. I created a CMake project (found here: https://github.com/PSUCompBio/cmake-visualstudio-msmpi) that compiles and runs fine **without** the inclusion of:

```
#include "mpi.h"
```

The steps I take to build the project are:
 1. use the Cmake-GUI application to configure and generate the makefile
 2. Use the open project button in the CMake-GUI to launch Visual Studio 2017.
 3. Set the HelloWorld solution as the startup project.
 4. Build (Got to top menu bar, then Build->Build Solution)

However, with the mpi.h included:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mpi.h"

int main()
{
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

the mpi.h is not found:
[visual studio error from build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28v9w.png)

My top level CmakeLists.txt file is pretty simple and does find MSMPI fine:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
PROJECT (hellocmake)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (src)
option(ENABLE_MPI "Enable MPI parallelization" OFF)
if(ENABLE_MPI)
    if(WIN32)
        find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
        if(MPI_FOUND)
            message("Using MPI")
        endif(MPI_FOUND)
    endif(WIN32)
endif(ENABLE_MPI)
```

And the structure of my project is:

```
-CMakeLists.txt
-src
----test.cpp
----CMakeLists.txt
```

My primary question is why is the mpi.h not being found? I can see that the MS MPI include directory is located by CMake-GUI (see following image):
[CMake-GUI configure showing MS MPI include path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V409D.png)

Is there another CMake command I need to place in my top level CMakeLists.txt file?

Below I show a portion of the CMakeCache.txt that deals with MPI options:

```
//Enable MPI parallelization
ENABLE_MPI:BOOL=ON

//Executable for running MPI programs.
MPIEXEC_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin/mpiexec.exe

//Maximum number of processors available to run MPI applications.
MPIEXEC_MAX_NUMPROCS:STRING=2

//Flag used by MPI to specify the number of processes for mpiexec;
// the next option will be the number of processes.
MPIEXEC_NUMPROC_FLAG:STRING=-n

//These flags will be placed after all flags passed to mpiexec.
MPIEXEC_POSTFLAGS:STRING=

//These flags will be directly before the executable that is being
// run by mpiexec.
MPIEXEC_PREFLAGS:STRING=

//MPI CXX additional include directories
MPI_CXX_ADDITIONAL_INCLUDE_DIRS:STRING=

//MPI compiler for CXX
MPI_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=MPI_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND

//MPI CXX compilation definitions
MPI_CXX_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS:STRING=

//MPI CXX compilation flags
MPI_CXX_COMPILE_OPTIONS:STRING=

//Path to a file.
MPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include

//MPI CXX libraries to link against
MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES:STRING=msmpi

//MPI CXX linker flags
MPI_CXX_LINK_FLAGS:STRING=

//If true, the MPI-2 C++ bindings are disabled using definitions.
MPI_CXX_SKIP_MPICXX:BOOL=OFF

//MPI C additional include directories
MPI_C_ADDITIONAL_INCLUDE_DIRS:STRING=

//MPI compiler for C
MPI_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=MPI_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND

//MPI C compilation definitions
MPI_C_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS:STRING=

//MPI C compilation flags
MPI_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS:STRING=

//Path to a file.
MPI_C_HEADER_DIR:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include

//MPI C libraries to link against
MPI_C_LIB_NAMES:STRING=msmpi

//MPI C linker flags
MPI_C_LINK_FLAGS:STRING=

//Location of the msmpi library for Microsoft MPI
MPI_msmpi_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x86/msmpi.lib

//Value Computed by CMake
hellocmake_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/rhk12/code/cmake-visualstudio-msmpi/build

//Value Computed by CMake
hellocmake_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/rhk12/code/cmake-visualstudio-msmpi
```

Thank you for any suggestions you might have.

Comment: Unless mpi.h is in the same folder as the file that includes it, you'll need to put angle brackets around it: `#include mpi.h`, but even that assumes that the path to your mpi.h file is on the includes path.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Post text, not links to images of text.

Comment: you need to have `cmake` use the MPI wrappers (e.g. `mpicc` and friends) instead of the compilers (e.g. `cc` and friends)

Comment: You show us a code with `find_package(MPI)` invocation, but don't show the code which uses results of this invocation (include directories, libraries and so). Exactly this part is responsible whether MPI headers will be found.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have been looking around in directories as well as online and it appears that when using MS MPI, cl is used to compile. Is mpicc even used to compile with MS MPI?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have pasted the output from CMakeCache.txt below. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I could not paste in comments. I pasted them in edited post above.

Comment: No, `CMakeCache.txt` is not a code. The code is in `CMakeLists.txt`. You show content only of top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, but there is also `src/CMakeLists.txt` script, which actually creates the executable and should adjust include directories for it.

Comment: @jwdonahue I confirmed that mpi.h is located in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include, which Cmake accurately picks up (see CMakeCache.txt posted above). Adding brackets did not help and was not the way I have seen this used in other examples online.

Comment: @Tsyvarev your question helped me fix the issue. I will update my post with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using the following CMakeLists.txt.

In top-level directory, CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

PROJECT (hellocmake)

option(ENABLE_MPI "Enable MPI parallelization" OFF)

if(ENABLE_MPI)
    find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_FLAGS} ${MPI_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${MPI_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${MPI_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif(ENABLE_MPI)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY (src)
```

Then in the src directory CMakeLists.txt

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hellocmake test.cpp)

if(ENABLE_MPI)
    target_link_libraries(hellocmake ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
endif(ENABLE_MPI)
```

Once I did this I went back to CMake-GUI and configured and generated Makefile, then selected open project which opened Visual Studio. When I build and run I get this:

```
Hello, World!!
Hello world from processor MNE-REKR02.engr.psu.edu, rank 0 out of 1 processors

C:\Users\rhk12\code\cmake-visualstudio-msmpi\build\src\Debug\hellocmake.exe (process 18728) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I am not sure how to specify the number of processors in visual studio. The CMake configuration found 2, but that is a different question.

Comment: The accepted solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163075/how-to-compile-an-mpi-included-c-program-using-cmake is imho more elegant