# Use MPI within CMake in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cmake, mpi, visual-studio-2019

I have a `C++` project that is implemented in Linux with `JetBrain CLion` IDE. To get the executable, I used `CMake` which is fully matched with `JetBrain CLion`. The project uses `MPI` to handle multi-node processing, and the project works fine in Linux.

Now, I have to get an executable for Windows too. So, I installed the community version of `Visual Studio 2019` along with `Microsft MPI` to build my project there too. I found that it might be easier to create the `sln` file for the project by `CMake` and then import the project into `VS`. But, when I tried this approach, I got an error for not finding `MPI`:

```
Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIB_NAMES MPI_C_HEADER_DIR MPI_C_WORKS) 
Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES MPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR MPI_CXX_WORKS) 
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1687 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:35 (find_package)
```

The cmake code that works in Linux is:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable(prjt main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(sub1)
add_subdirectory(sub2)
target_link_libraries(prjt ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET prjt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

After reading [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637900/using-cmake-microsoft-mpi-and-visual-studio-2017-cannot-find-mpi-h) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163075/how-to-compile-an-mpi-included-c-program-using-cmake), I also tried:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Program Files/Microsoft MPI")
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_FLAGS} ${MPI_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${MPI_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${MPI_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
add_executable(prjt main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(sub1)
add_subdirectory(sub2)
target_link_libraries(prjt ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET prjt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

but still no success.

I also tried to link MPI directly via MSVS, as it is instructed in [[3]](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/), but it did not work too. The problem within that approach is that when I call `set MSMPI`, I only get `MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\` and I do not get the rest of the environment variables. In the `Linker` of `MSVS` also I manually added the `Microst SDK` address. (I also added the other required environment variables as [[4]](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~mputhawala/PPT.pdf) explains)

I appreciate any help or comment.

Comment: You cannot have whitespace in the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` string. Try `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ MPI")`.

Comment: @kanstar I tried that and still same error.

Comment: The path you provide in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` must contain a file called `MPIConfig.cmake` or `MPI-config.cmake`. Otherwise `find_package` won't find the package. So make sure to point to the directory where one of those are present.

Comment: @kanstar I checked all directories and neither of them contains either `MPIConfig.cmake` or `MPI-config.cmake`. I install `MS-MPI v10.0` Is there anything that I need to install?

Comment: So, I think MPI is not shipped with a config file. But CMake ships already with a [`FindMPI.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindMPI.cmake) file. Read the documentation of the file to get a grasp on what variables are defined.