# Compiling program with openMP with CLION on Windows

Tags: c++, openmp, clion

I have downloaded openMP using cygwin which i use as compiler in CLION.

I have included

```
#include <omp.h>
```

and used its schemas e.g

```
#pragma omp paraller
        #pragma omp single
```

however when i use `omp_get_max_threads()`  it throws

> undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'

error, i tried to add compiler arguments:
[image]

But the error remains the same. Is there a way how to fix this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of CLION, but are the *Program arguments* really the arguments for the compiler for your compiled code?

Usually, when compiling an OpenMP source file, the `-fopenmp` flag need to be added to both the compiler and linker.  So, for instance:

```
gcc -fopenmp -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -fopenmp -c bar.c -o bar.o
gcc -fopenmp -o app.exe foo.o bar.o
```

Or if you comoile and link using just one source file:

```
gcc -fopenmp -c fooc -o app.exe
```

PS: There's a typo, it should be `#pragma omp parallel` instead of `#pragma omp paraller`.

Comment: indeed, the flag `-fopenmp` shouldn't be added to parameters, but inside `parameter`, in `build`.

Answer (score 0):

**CLion** uses **CMake** as a build system, **OpenMP** support was drastically improved in **CMake 3.9+**. Now, you need to configure your **CMakeLists.txt** file as follow:

For example, consider the example code below.

### OpenMP code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout << "Greetings from process " << id << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "parallel for ends " << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

The `CMakeLists.txt` file will be like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(openmp_test) # you can change the project name

find_package(OpenMP)

add_executable(openmp_para_test main.cpp)

if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(openmp_para_test PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
endif()
```

If you are not familiar with CMake, [Here a quick CMake tutorial to use with CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html).

Comment: same answer as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399422/how-to-set-linker-flags-for-openmp-in-cmakes-try-compile-function/12404666#12404666

Comment: @MarineGalantin Here, it's rather a recommendation than an answer.