# How to configure CMakeLists.txt for OpenMP?

Tags: cmake, openmp

I am building a python extension from c++ shared library.
This library is using some openmp pragma.

I would like to know how to configure CMakeLists.txt in order to include openmp ?
I have added the openmp flag `-fopenmp`
But I still have this error : `undefined symbol: GOMP_critical_end`

here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++lastest -pthread -fopenmp") 

project (py_interface)

#find_library('gomp')
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED) 

include_directories(/usr/include/python3.6/)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

set(SRC interface.cpp)

add_library(py_interface SHARED ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(py_interface PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

set_property(TARGET py_interface PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

Comment: Does changing the `target_link_libraries` call to `target_link_libraries(py_interface PRIVATE ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
` fix the problem?

Comment: Are there multiple compilers on your system? Maybe the program is compiled with one compiler but linked to another compiler's OpenMP library. `ldd` on your compiled binary will show which library you are linking against.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set linker flags for OpenMP in CMake's try\_compile function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399422/how-to-set-linker-flags-for-openmp-in-cmakes-try-compile-function)