# Undefined Reference to 'omp_get_wtime'

Tags: c, cmake, error-handling, openmp, clion

I am trying to run a C program on Clion using OpenMP. All my earlier programs ran but for some reason this one isnt. I have included the following in my main.c file:

```
#include "qdbmp.h"
#include "qdbmp.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <intrin.h>
```

Following is my cmake file content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(myproject C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(myproject 
        main.c
        qdbmp.h
        test.h
)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(myproject -fopenmp)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

I tried changing my cmake file and removing and adding openmp to my main.c but nothing worked. Any help is appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set linker flags for OpenMP in CMake's try\_compile function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399422/how-to-set-linker-flags-for-openmp-in-cmakes-try-compile-function)